# How to get the total watch time or played time of the video in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created the video player using chewie controller and I need to get the total watch or played time of video for the particular user and I need to update it in database. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` and `position` in the video controller .

Comment: Would you please explain please?

Comment: @Jagan do you want the time to add up? So if I watched the video 3 times = durationOfVideo *3 ? Or do you want to save the position? If you want to save the position: videoController.value.position.inSeconds gives the position in seconds.

Comment: @MiroLiebschner I need to get the time where the user stopped the video watching either he had quit the app or came back or paused.

Comment: Then do it like this: Use the videoController.value.position.inSeconds and save it when the user closes the video. After the video is reopened skip to the saved position.inSeconds.